# Implicit call of Class constructor from Initialisation of another class

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

The following code-snippet seemingly works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Filling{
public:
  const int num;
  Filling(int num_)
  : num(num_)
  { }
};
class Nougat{
public:
  Nougat(const Filling& filling)
  : reference(filling)
  { }
  const Filling& get_filling() const{ return reference; }
private:
  const Filling& reference;
};
class Wrapper{
public:
  Wrapper(const Nougat& nougat)
  : reference(nougat)
  { }
  const Nougat& get_nougat() const{ return reference; };
private:
  const Nougat& reference;
};

int main(){
  Filling filling(3);
  Wrapper wrap(filling); /*(0)*/
  std::cout << wrap.get_nougat().get_filling().num << std::endl;
}
```

Although the initialisation is improper (at `/*(0)*/`), because the `Wrapper` class should accept a `Nougat` class, but instead it is given a `Filling` class.

Since the constructor takes references, I believe the compiler is creating a temporary `Nougat` class from the constructor argument, and then passes that to initialise the `Wrapper` class.

Getting a reference from a temporary results in undefined behaviour.

Is this what is really happening?

If so, how can this code compile?

Comment: `Nougat` constructor from `Filling&` is not `explicit`, and so can be used for implicit conversions. `Wrapper wrap(filling);` is interpreted as `Wrapper wrap(Nougat(filling));`, creating a temporary `Nougat` object and passing that to `Wrapper`. The temporary is then destroyed, leaving `wrap` with a dangling reference. The subsequent attempt to use that reference exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I added the explicit keyword: `explicit Wrapper(const Nougat& nougat) ...` and it still compiles...

Comment: Is it okay to extend the question with, "how to forbid this kind of implicit behavior" ?

Comment: It's the `Nougat` constructor that's being used for implicit conversion, not `Wrapper` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wrapper`'s constructor expects a reference to `Nougat`, but you are giving it a `Filling`. As with all function calls in C++, in such a situation *implicit conversion sequences* for all arguments are considered.

An implicit conversion sequence could be for example a cast from a derived class reference to a base class reference, but since `Nougat` and `Filling` are not related in that way, this doesn't apply here.

Another allowed step in an implicit conversion sequence are user-defined conversions. This also includes so-called *converting constructors* of the target type, that is a constructor not marked `explicit`. This is the case for the constructor `Nougat(const Filling& filling)`, which allows for conversion from `Filling` to `Nougat`.

So, this constructor may be called to construct a temporary object of `Nougat` type as an implicit conversion. The resulting temporary can bind to a `const` lvalue reference as well.

To avoid such unintentional conversions, you should mark constructors as `explicit`, at least if they take exactly one argument, except if you really intent for such implicit conversions to happen.

---

By the end of the construction of `wrapper`, the temporary object is destroyed and therefore the reference obtained in

```
wrap.get_nougat()
```

is dangling, and it's following use causes undefined behavior.